# Creating a new Image file in astropy with specified dimensions of another image file

Tags: python, astropy, fits

I'm having a problem wit fits file manipulation in the astropy package, and I'm in need of some help.

I essentially want to take an image I have in fits file format, and create a new file I need to start inputing correction factors to and a new image which can then be used with the correction factors and the original image to produce a correction image. Each of these will have the same dimensions.

Starting with this:

```
from astropy.io import fits

# Compute the size of the images (you can also do this manually rather than calling these keywords from the header):
#URL: /Users/UCL_Astronomy/Documents/UCL/PHASG199/M33_UVOT_sum/UVOTIMSUM/M33_sum_epoch1_um2_norm.img
nxpix_um2_ext1 = fits.open('...')[1]['NAXIS1']
nypix_um2_ext1 = fits.open('...')[1]['NAXIS2']
#nxpix_um2_ext1 = 4071 #hima_sk_um2[1].header['NAXIS1'] # IDL: nxpix_uw1_ext1 = sxpar(hima_sk_uw1_ext1,'NAXIS1')
#nypix_um2_ext1 = 4321 #hima_sk_um2[1].header['NAXIS2'] # IDL: nypix_uw1_ext1 = sxpar(hima_sk_uw1_ext1,'NAXIS2')

# Make a new image file with the same dimensions (and headers, etc) to save the correction factors:
coicorr_um2_ext1 = ??[nxpix_um2_ext1,nypix_um2_ext1]

# Make a new image file with the same dimensions (and headers, etc) to save the corrected image:
ima_sk_coicorr_um2_ext1 = ??[nxpix_um2_ext1,nypix_um2_ext1]
```

Can anyone give me the obvious knowledge I am missing to do this...the last two lines are just there to outline what is missing. I have included ?? to perhaps signal I need something else there perhaps fits.writeto() or something similar...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think @VincePs answer is correct but I'll add some more information because I think you are not using the capabilities of `astropy` well here.

First of all Python is zero-based so the primary extension has the number `0`. Maybe you got that wrong, maybe you don't - but it's uncommon to access the second `HDU` so I thought I better mention it.

```
hdu_num = 0 # Or use = 1 if you really want the second hdu.
```

First you do not need to open the same file twice, you can open it once and close it after extracting the relevant values:

```
with fits.open('...') as hdus:
    nxpix_um2_ext1 = hdus[hdu_num]['NAXIS1']
    nxpix_um2_ext1 = hdus[hdu_num]['NAXIS2']
# Continue without indentation and the file will be closed again.
```

or if you want to keep the whole header (for saving it later) and the data you can use:

```
with fits.open('...') as hdus:
    hdr = hdus[hdu_num].header
    data = hdus[hdu_num].data # I'll also take the data for comparison.
```

I'll continue with the second approach because I think it's a lot cleaner and you'll have all the data and header values ready.

```
new_data = np.zeros((hdr['NAXIS2'], hdr['NAXIS1']))
```

Please note that Python interprets the axis different than IRAF (and I think IDL, but I'm not sure) so you need axis2 as first and axis1 as second element.

So do a quick check that the shapes are the same:

```
print(new_data.shape)
print(data.shape)
```

If they are not equal I got confused about the axis in Python (again) but I don't think so. But instead of creating a new array based on the `header` values you can also create a new array by just using the old shape:

```
new_data_2 = np.zeros(data.shape)
```

That will ensure the dimensions and shape is identical. Now you have an empty image. If you rather like a copy then you can, but do not need to, explicitly copy the data (except if you opened the file explicitly in write/append/update mode then you should always copy it but that's not the default.)

```
new_data = data # or = data.copy() for explicitly copying.
```

Do your operations on it and if you want to save it again you can use what @VinceP suggested:

```
hdu = fits.PrimaryHDU(new_data, header=hdr) # This ensures the same header is written to the new file
hdulist = fits.HDUList([hdu])
hdulist.writeto('new.fits')
```

Please note that you don't have to alter the shape-related header keywords even if you changed the data's shape because during `writeto` astropy will update these (by default)

Comment: I agree with @MSeifer's second tip of using `data.shape` instead of the NAXIS headers in the FITS file.  Those are implementation details of FITS that, reasonably, any user should not have to think about (in practice this is not always possible or the most efficient way because FITS is a kludgy format, and pyfits has some kludgy implementation details as well).  But in general don't look at the FITS header for anything but metadata.

Comment: @MSeifert, thanks for clarifying some aspects in more depth. I agree with all of them. You are totally right about X1,X2 being swapped in python with respect to iraf. It can be very confusing at times.

Comment: @MSeifert Hi Michael. This is working as explained. However, it gets a little tricky with what I want to do with it after. Could we somehow share details and I could enlist your help (with a small financial reward, if you're interested?)

Comment: @user3125347 I would recommend if you have any general and specific question that you just open another question here on StackOverflow or the astropy mailing list (if it is getting in-depth the mailing list would be a better place). I'm not sure if I could answer or explain how you can process your image (I don't know the details) but I'll certainly check StackOverflow frequently and if I do know the answer I will supply one and I don't need financial rewards for it.

Comment: @MSeifert That's admirable. What I will do is update my script with your suggestions and then resubmit the next steps I need help with here. Keep an eye out for it. I have incidentally sent it off to the astropy mailing list but nothing as yet has been returned.

Comment: No problem, do not forget to accept either mine or @VincePs answer if any of these solves your question. And I'll certainly check for other questions here.

Comment: @MSeifert I've accepted yours since it now firms the bulk of my new script. I've just posted a new question up here. Hopefully it's not too lengthy.

Answer (score 2):

The astropy [documentation](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/fits/) takes you though this task step by step: create an array with size (NAXIS1,NAXIS2), put the data in the primary HDU, make an HDUlist and write it to disk:

```
import numpy as np
from astropy.io import fits

data = np.zeros((NAXIS2,NAXIS1))
hdu = fits.PrimaryHDU(data)
hdulist = fits.HDUList([hdu])

hdulist.writeto('new.fits')
```

Comment: Would you mind  editing your answer with swapped ``NAXIS1`` and ``NAXIS2``? I think if someone else stumbles over this question and reads your answer it should provide the correct code. :-)